# Give access from admin panel to users that registered in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

So, I am trying to allow users to login after they registered **AND** only after I decide whether they are eligible for signing in or not.

Basically, the flow that I'd like is the next one:

1. user tries to log in -> if he is not registered, click on a register link **(done)**
2. user type in some data in the registration form and submits it **(done)**
3. now, the data will appear in Django admin panel.

I would like a way of approving users data, and only after, to allow him to sign in.

My code so far:

**forms.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30)), label=_("Username"), error_messages={ 'invalid': _("This value must contain only letters, numbers and underscores.") })
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30)), label=_("Email address"))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30, render_value=False)), label=_("Password"))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30, render_value=False)), label=_("Password (again)"))

    def clean_username(self):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("The username already exists. Please try another one."))

    def clean(self):
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields did not match."))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form
    })

    return render_to_response(
        'registration/register.html',
        variables,
    )

def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response(
        'registration/success.html',
    )

def logout_page(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

@login_required
def home(request):
    return render_to_response(
        'home.html', {
            'user': request.user
        }
    )
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_page),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register),
    url(r'^register/success/$', views.register_success),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

**login.html**

```
<form method="post" action=".">
            {% if form.errors %}
                <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
            {% endif %}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table border="0">
                <tr><th><label for="id_username">Name:</label></th><td>{{ form.username }}</td></tr>
                <tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td>{{ form.password }}</td></tr>
            </table>
            <div class="send">
                <div class="now" style="text-align: center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/home" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**register.html**

```
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    <table border="0">
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Any ideas, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save user with `is_active` flag false, and then when you decide activate that user (`is_active` to True). Users with `is_active=False` can't log in but appear for you in admin panel.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
        )
user.is_active = False
user.save()
```

Comment: when I am adding that, I get the following error: `ModelBase object got multiple values for keyword argument 'is_active'` . Any ideas ?

Comment: I edited my answer, now that will definitely work.  That error before was caused by `create_user` implementation which accepts `extra_fields` but has hardcoded `is_active=True` on model creation.

Comment: But it's finally [fixed in master branch](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L139). But in [1.8](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L178) it's still there.

Comment: Thanks. It worked flawless. Do you also have any idea of how can I get the input of the form and parse it to a variable in,let's say `script.py` ?

Comment: Just take out the part with `form` from your register function and put it in `script.py` and instead of creating `user`, return `form.cleaned_data`. Don't forget to pass `request.POST` to that function. I guess you got the idea already.